# Failed to Decode JSON error in Angular Http

Tags: json, angularjs

```
$scope.reload = function(){
    send = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/pipelines',
        data: JSON.stringify({"type":$scope.selectedType,"Plan":$scope.selectedPlan}),
        headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'  
        }
    };
    console.log(send);
    $http(send).then(function(response){
        $scope.pipelines = response.data;
    },function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
```

This leads to Bad request and console outputs error as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</p>\n"
```

This is  using AngularJS 1.6 for.

I am trying to figure out What is wrong with the JSON object.

Comment: I can't tell if this is your problem, but generally you do not stringify your data object, you just assign your object to `data`.

Comment: @Crowcoder  you're right here , I don't need that since headers already includes 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'. 
I couldn't understand though what s the issue in decoding